# Get both return values of a promise chain

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

I have a promise chain inside of a function and I would like to `console.log` the values returned from 2 functions inside of the chain. How would I do this? With my current code I get the value from `si.cpuTemperature()` then `undefined` but I would like to get the value from `si.cpu()` then `si.cpuTemperature()`.

```
const si = require('systeminformation');

function getCPUInfo() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        resolve();
        console.log("Gathering CPU information...");
        return si.cpu()
        // .then(data => cpuInfo = data) - no need for this, the promise will resolve with "data"
        .catch(err => console.log(err)); // note, doing this will mean on error, this function will return a RESOLVED (not rejected) value of `undefined`
    })
    .then(() => {
        return si.cpuTemperature().catch(err => console.log(err));
    });
}

getCPUInfo().then((data1, data2) => console.log(data1, data2));
```

Comment: So, what do you want `data1` and `data2` to be? si.cpu and si.cpuTemperature?

Comment: Seems like you should just be using `Promise.all([si.cpu(), si.cpuTemperature()]).then(console.log)`

Comment: I'm not understanding the construction of the Promise (or the call of `resolve` immediately), can't you just call `.then` on your existing promises?

Comment: note: `Get both return values of a promise chain` makes no sense, since there is only one result in a promise chain

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/systeminformation),

`systeminformation.method()` returns a promise. So you don't really need to wrap it inside a promise constructor, ie `new Promise()`

To get the cpu and temperature, since they are not dependent on each other, you can do either use parallel promises along with an async function or just parallel promises

```
async function getCpuAndTemperature() {
  const [cpu, temperature] = await Promise.all([
      si.cpu(),
      si.cpuTemperature()
  ])

  console.log(cpu, temperature)
}
```

or

```
function getCpuAndTemperature() {
  return Promise.all([
      si.cpu(),
      si.cpuTemperature()
  ])
  .then(([cpu, temperature]) => {
    console.log(cpu, temperature)
  })
}
```